# SQL Server CLR Method Timing Out randomly

Tags: sql-server, xml, clr, connection-timeout

I have a SQL CLR Assembly sending an XML message to software on a separate server to essentially cartonize orders (figure out the best way place items in a box). It has been running successfully for several months and now it appears that the response message from the cartonizing software does not return and the process times out and fails. We have determined with WireShark that the message does indeed make it to the server, then to the software, it gets processed then it gets sent back to the source. But it somehow gets lost in translation on the response back to the database server from the server doing the cartonization. I can reproduce this issue over and over again with the same XML message. This CLR method still succeeds for every other order and XML message. In fact, the response was sent back successfully for about 10 minutes, then it went back to timing out again. I cant explain it and I have exhausted all resources to figure out exactly why this keeps happening.

I'm Using Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I would paste the code executing and creating the procedures, but it will be greater than 30000 characters and wont fit in the window. Any help would be much appreciated. If there is any more info you need please let me know!

Comment: So its specific to a single order? And is the response arriving at the database server at the network level?

Comment: The CLR is producing XML? Out of curiosity, why CLR at all?

Comment: @DaleBurrell Yes it is, and the response is arriving back to the database server at the network level accoring to WireShark. I can see traffic getting sent and received.

Comment: @BenThul No, the XML Message is getting generated before the CLR send. The SQL CLR is just sending and receiving the XML message.

Comment: I wonder if the XML message is corrupt or has an invalid character and the parsing fails at a lower level than your CLR method, but higher then the network layer? Tricky...

Comment: @DaleBurrell That's what i was afraid of... And tricky is right. Any software you know of that could do any validation of the message to try and find corrupt values?

Comment: 'fraid not - I assume you've checked the windows event log?